# How to use SSL in Java correctly?

Tags: java, ssl

Unfortunately I'm completely new to SSL. Currently I'm trying to set up a secure connection between a client and a server application in Java and the following code works for me (transmitted data is encrypted), but I don't know if this is a correct and secure solution.

Client side:

```
socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(host, port);

socket.setUseClientMode(true);
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
socket.startHandshake();
```

Server side:

```
sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) serverSocketFactory.createServerSocket(requestPort());

sslServerSocket.setUseClientMode(false);
sslServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslServerSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
```

Comment: `socket.setUseClientMode(true);` is redundant, as you are already the client; `sslServerSocket.setUseClientMode(false);` is redundant as you are already the server; socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());` is insecure; and `socket.startHandshake();` is unnecessary.

Comment: Okay, so could you please show me how to do it right? And why is this insecure? As I said, I'm new to SSL so I'd appreciate a little explanation.

Comment: How to do it right is to remove all the code I mentioned. The 'supported' cipher suites' include those that are insecure: too broad to cover here. Your code should work without using them, otherwise you have a certificate problem somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to enable all ciphers/protocols. Better that you enabled only the ciphers and protocols you want. If both server and server is written by you, choose what you want and configure only that.

```
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(...);
socket.setEnabledProtocols(...);
```

Supported ciphers and protocols can be seen in [JSSE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider)

Or you can use "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithm" to control what algs you want to use.

Comment: It is better in most circumstances not to fiddle around with enabled cipher suites at all, at least in client code.